# Get grandfather in jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outter">
....
  <div class="container" rel="identification" >
    <h4> <a href="#" href="www.test.com"> </h4>
  </div>
....
</div>
```

And I have some jquery code that looks like:

```
$('.outter').delegate('.container a','click', function()
{
  //If $(this) is the a element, how can I get the rel attribute of the granfather div?
}
```

If it is possible without making it dependent with the h4 parent, just in case someday changes for h3, for example.

Comment: `.closest('.container')`. jQuery's API document is very good, you should have a look at it. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('div.container').attr('rel');
```

Comment: Just saw it just looks in the ancestors :).

Comment: In that case, you can use the less elegant `$(this).parent().parent()`

Comment: closest just goes to the ancestors, so is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parents() method which matches parents against a selector

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Or if you're using 1.4 there is a new parentsUntil() method

http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Answer (score 0):

If just this is the case:

```
<div class="container" rel="identification" >
   <h4> 
     <a href="#">click</a> 
   </h4>
</div>
```

then:    <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/PUmWB/</kbd>

```
$('a').click(function(){
   alert($('div.container').attr('rel'));
});
```